# Using input from html boxes in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Currently, I am trying to learn js.
At this moment, I can make some simple functional scripts. But whenever I want user input, I still have to us a prompt, which can become quite annoying.
Therefore, I want to use HTML boxes for user input.

I put the box in HTML like this:

```
<FORM>
    <INPUT type="button" value="Fill Me In" name="box1">
</FORM>
```

But how do I call the input in javascript then?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want JS to react in the `event` the client `clicks on` the `box1` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as follow :

```
<FORM>
    <INPUT type="button" value="Fill Me In" name="box1" id="txt">
</FORM>
```

Javascript :

```
var txtval=document.getElementById("txt").value;
```

or :

you can create custom dialog and show it using javascript or jquery(best option)

For more about dialog refer [This link](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Answer (score 2):

There are various methods to get input textbox value:

**Method 1:**

```
document.getElementById('textbox_id').value to get the value of desired box

Eg. document.getElementById("searchTxt").value;
```

*Note : Method 2,3,4 and 6 returns a collection of elements called NodeList, so use [whole_number] to get the desired occurence, for first element use [0] and for second one use 1 and so on...*

**Method 2:**

```
Use document.getElementsByClassName('class_name')[whole_number].value which returns a Live Nodelist

Eg. document.getElementsByClassName("searchField")[0].value;
if this is the first textbox in your page.
```

**Method 3:**

Use document.getElementsByTagName('tag_name')[whole_number].value which also returns a live nodelist

```
Eg. document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value; ,
if this is the first textbox in your page.
```

**Method 4:**

document.getElementsByName('name')[whole_number].value

```
Eg. document.getElementsByName("searchTxt")[0].value; 
if this is the first textbox with name 'searchtext' in your page.
```

**Method 5:**

Use powerful document.querySelector('selector').value which uses CSS selector to select element

```
Eg. document.querySelector('#searchTxt').value; selected by id
document.querySelector('.searchField').value; selected by class
document.querySelector('input').value; selected by tagname
 document.querySelector('[name="searchTxt"]').value; selected by name
```

**Method 6:**

document.querySelectorAll('selector')[whole_number].value which also uses CSS selector to select elements but it returns all elements with that selector as a static nodelist.

```
Eg. document.querySelectorAll('#searchTxt')[0].value; selected by id 
document.querySelectorAll('.searchField')[0].value; selected by class 
document.querySelectorAll('input')[0].value; selected by tagname
document.querySelectorAll('[name="searchTxt"]')[0].value; selected by name
```

Comment: Sorry, but I am quite new to javascript, and I don't understand anything from you answer...

Comment: The thing is, the DOM - the HTML structure you have to query when asking for a specific element (like your input) can be asked for the input in quite a few ways. One which gets you that exact element is `document.getElementById()` as the post above suggests. It's propably your best bet for now. Once you get the input element, you can read as well as write the contents with the `.value` attribute.

Comment: @MildlyInteresting thnks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

You can use [window.openDialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.openDialog) to open a window as a dialog:

```
var retValues = { box1: null };
var win = openDialog("your_form.html", "dlg", "modal", retVals);
alert(retValues.box1);
```

Then your dialog:

```
<FORM onsubmit="window.arguments[1].box1 = document.getElementById('txt').value; close();">
    <INPUT type="button" value="Fill Me In" name="box1" id="txt">
</FORM>
```